# PHP Date create From Format inside a function/non object error

Tags: php, date

I have the following code producing this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\grid2.php on line 58

I am trying to set up this function to take in a date string as below, apply the time offset, then output it back out in the format set up in the function call... but no luck.

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) session_start();
$_SESSION["timeoffset"] = "Europe/Amsterdam";


function formatDate($date, $format){
// use the the appropriate timezone for your stamp
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// set it to whatever you want to convert it
$timestamp->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($_SESSION["timeoffset"]));
echo $timestamp->format($format);   
}

formatDate('2012-10-14T21:15', 'Y-m-d\TH:i');
?>
```

I am also trying to figure out how return the string with a certain number of added minutes amount of minutes.

So the string  "2012-10-14T21:15" would have 5 minutes added = "2012-10-14T21:20"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will return false on failure. This means that:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

has failed and that $timestamp is false (var_dump($timestamp) will show you). Without knowing what you're passing in as your parameters for function formatDate, I don't think anyone will be able to figure out exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I was passing this to the function: formatDate('2012-10-14T21:15', 'Y-m-d\TH:i');
it works, however formatDate('2012-10-14T21:15', 'g:ia'); does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rather

`$timestamp->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));`

I think the `sessions` array isn't returning the string `Europe/Amsterdam`.

Do the debugging

Comment: I had a dual instance of the function from an older version -  however it only works if keep the formatting of the original object 'Y-m-d\TH:i', i can't use the format 'g:ia' for example (if i just want to pull the time and am/pm       formatDate('2012-10-14T21:15', 'Y-m-d\TH:i'); works but formatDate('2012-10-14T21:15', 'g:ia'); does not...?